# Android SupportMapFragment can't see map inside a fragment

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to add a SupportMapFragment into a FrameLayout in my code but i get a Null Pointer Exeption.

**My Code:**

**MainFragment:**

```
public class MainFragment extends FragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);       
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);             
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        SecondFragment second = new SecondFragment();
        ft.add(R.main_activity.frame, second);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }       
}
```

**SecondFragment:**

```
public class SecondFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_map, null);       
    }
}
```

**My XML:**

**activity_main:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        layout="@layout/header" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7.06" 
        android:id="@+main_activity/frame"
        android:background="@drawable/defaultbg"/>

    <include
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        layout="@layout/footer" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_map:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment        
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**My Logcat:**

```
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.WhosAround/com.WhosAround.MainFragment}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at maps.z.r.onResume(Unknown Source)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$Stub.onTransact(IMapFragmentDelegate.java:115)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:279)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onResume(Unknown Source)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onResume(Unknown Source)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.e$1.a(Unknown Source)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.e.a(Unknown Source)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.e.onResume(Unknown Source)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onResume(Unknown Source)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1503)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1070)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:1871)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:455)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:444)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3867)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
03-07 21:20:17.160: E/AndroidRuntime(1617):     ... 12 more
```

Comment: Unrelated but you don't need to call `beginTransaction` twice.  You can remove this line from MainFragment.java `ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();`

Comment: yeah you write that because i've deleted some lines after pasting the code

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your simply forgetting to call `super.onCreateView();` in your `SecondFragment`.

If you override `onCreateView()` of SupportMapFragment you need to remember to call the super method as this is where all the "action" happens.

Comment: I can't say its not awkward:)

Comment: @AsafNevo well it's a common mistake as you normally wouldn't call it in fragments onCreateView(); SupportMapFragment is the exception :)

Comment: Thanks god for stackoverflow.com :)

Comment: i called super.onCreateView(); but still getting an error
Act i m adding map dynamically

Comment: @user3243147 then you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: Warpzit: Act i am adding map at run time(Adding map dynamically)

Comment: @user3243147 you should start a new post with logcat etc. can't help from comments.

Comment: Warpzit: post my logcat

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem too, so my temporary solution is don't use SupportMapFragment to change using MapFragment.

hope this can help you.